# ASP.NET MVC - Creating SAAS framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, saas

I currently have a ASP.NET MVC 2 web application and would like to enhance the architecture to support a SAAS model.  I plan on eventually building a number of web applications so would like to design the system accordingly.

The goal would be that when a client would hit the following url ***clientxyz.domain.com*** they would see an image of all their subscribed applications.  This would essentially be a web page with a bunch of application icons.  Once a client would click on a icon it would navigate to that actual web app at the following example url **clientxyz.domain.com/application_name**.

We currently use GoDaddy to host our domain and plan on using a Cloud based iLand server to host our application.  We only plan on a few new clients a year due to the nature of our software.

I have a number of questions:

1. Is it possible to programmatically create subdomains on the fly using a .Net api.  I'm pretty sure GoDaddy does not let you do it.  So is there another provider that would let me create subdomains via C#.  This may be the wrong approach and may not even need to physically create client subdomains. Instead I may be able to accomplish this using url rewriting in IIS/MVC??  If I use rewriting, it would have to satisfy the url requirements mentioned above.  Any suggestions/links/examples?
2. Should I create a separate IIS website for each tenant/client? Or should I use URL rewriting and simply have a single website / application pool?  Looks like you can programmatically spin up IIS websites (example: http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/csharp/d4bba585-b517-4834-8476-ff05b085d86e/iis--create-app-pools-virtual-directories-and-web-sites-c-net.aspx)
3. Since we are using a Virtual Server on iLand do I simply have to point GoDaddy to the nameserver at iLand.
4. I would like to automate the entire new client process if possible.  To accomplish this, I would have to created the database (probably going to have single db per tenant), populate the global client/tenant table, create admin user account and subscription details in newly created database and create subdomain depending on approach.  Am I missing anything?

thanks in advance.